# Conditional to polymorphism - a more complicated case

Tags: design-patterns, polymorphism, refactoring

Say I have this well known [example](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html):

```
   double getSpeed() {
       switch (_type) {
           case EUROPEAN:
              return getBaseSpeed();
           case AFRICAN:
              return getBaseSpeed() - getLoadFactor() * _numberOfCoconuts;
           case NORWEGIAN_BLUE:
              return (_isNailed) ? 0 : getBaseSpeed(_voltage);
       }
       throw new RuntimeException ("Should be unreachable");
   }
```

Obviously, I'd refactor into subclasses and everything will be made right in the world again. But what if I have:

```
   double getSpeed() {
       switch (_type) {
           case EUROPEAN:
              inform_gary(_count);  
              return getBaseSpeed();
           case AFRICAN:
              increment_package_counter();
              transmit_coordinates(_coordinates);
              return getBaseSpeed() - getLoadFactor() * _numberOfCoconuts;
           case NORWEGIAN_BLUE:              
              return (_isNailed) ? 0 : getBaseSpeed(_voltage);
       }
       throw new RuntimeException ("Should be unreachable");
   }
```

Now it would be useless to subclass because then I'd have to tightly couple the subclasses to code they shouldn't know about. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: I think you need to revisit what `getSpeed` is responsible for. Why does it need to send coordinates or inform Gary?

Comment: I guess I didn't give the best example. The switch statement I have is inside a router. Based on a message it received it has to do one or more of: update internal state, select some data, pass that data on to a different component. I'd like to get rid of the switch statement, but I can't see how.

Answer (score 1):

The question's comments refine the question a bit; I'll answer the updated version.

---

I would make a class for each possible message type. These would inherit a message interface with an `execute` function.

Often, a message will need to perform some actions which require references to the execution *environment*. Since life is much easier when message objects are immutable, I would pass these references as a parameter to the `execute` function.

The interface:

```
interface Message
{
    void execute(Context context)
}
```

And an example message:

```
class RebroadcastMessage : Message
{
    private final String content;
    private final int timeToLive;

    public RebroadcastMessage(String content, int timeToLive) {

        this.content = content;
        this.timeToLive = timeToLive;
    }

    void execute(Context context)
    {
        if (timeToLive > 0)
        {
            foreach (Peer p in context.Peers)
            {
                context.send(p, new RebroadcastMessage(content, timeToLive - 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This makes processing messages easy:

```
messageQueue.take().execute(this.context);
```

---

Based on the discussion below, I will explain another technique.

Sometimes you want to handle state *between* messages, but do not want to put this logic in the message receiving class. In these cases, I would suggest an event-driven design.

A `Session` takes messages (e.g. from a network connection) and updates all listeners for each message received.

```
interface MessageListener 
{
    void handle(Context context, Message message);
}

interface Session
{
    void addListener(MessageListener listener);
}
```

You can then implement separate a `MessageListener` for each bit of functionality you require.

```
class FruitTracker implements MessageListener 
{
    private Set<Fruit> stock;

    public FruitTracker()
    {
        stock = new HashSet<>();
    }

    void handle(Context context, Message message)
    {
        if (message instanceof StockQueryMessage)
        {
            context.send(context.getSender(), new StockQuoteMessage(stock));
        } 
        else if (message instanceof StockUpdateMessage)
        {
            stock = ((StockUpdate)message).getStock();
        }
    }
}
```

Set up:

```
val fruitTracker = new FruitTracker();

session.addListener(fruitTracker);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that mean the `Message` would then have to know things about the context? For example, it would have to know which data to select and how to select it before passing it on.

Comment: `Message` would only know about it's execution context when it is executed. That is why it is a function parameter, not a class member.

Comment: Let's say one subclass of `Message` has to send `context.getData().getOranges()` and another `context.getData().getApples()`. If I ever change the structure of what's returned by `getData()` I'd have to make changes to every subclass of `Message` too. Ideally I'd query for the data in the calling class and pass that on to `Message`, but then I'd be back to using a conditional.

Comment: The content of a message should not depend on the context. You should know what a message contains before you create it so that the contents can be passed to the message constructor.

Comment: But I can only know what it should contain based on the received message (i.e. not `Message`). So I have to prepare a payload based on the received message, instantiate a `Message` object (again based on the received message) and then call `execute`.

Comment: OK, I think I asked a stupid question here. From looking over a few examples it appears this pattern is more suited to cases where the logic can be cleanly separated and moved into a subclass. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: @Johnny Yes about subclasses (no about stupid questions). The refactoring book by Fowler et al states "One of the grandest sounding words in object jargon is polymorphism. The essence of polymorphsim [sic] is that it allows you to avoid writing an explicit conditional when you have objects whose behavior varies depending on their *types*." (emphasis is mine). It's also a useful refactoring because you can add new cases as a kind of plug-in functionality. Applying it blindly could result in spreading out the conditional logic into sub-classes, and doesn't add value.